# SELECT DISTINCT with so many conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a Filter feature for my website. I was told to use `SELECT DISTICT` to accomplish this. Below is what I currently have, it retrieves all the distinct values in column STATE and displays them as check boxes so the user can check those states he wants displayed on a table on the page.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT state FROM allproperties";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='state' value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[0] . "<br>";
}
```

My problem is this Filter feature will have a lot of conditions, not just selecting which States to show, there'd be selections for which county, member age, member contributions etch. When the user clicks DISPLAY button to display the filtered results, I do not know how to build an SQL query for this. If only a few condition I can simply use "SELECT * WHERE (...) AND (....)" but if I use this for a filter feature, there'd be a lot of conditions like:

`WHERE (state='CA' OR state='NV' OR state='WA' ..... so on and so fort)`

Is there a way to do it like `WHERE state=OR('CA','NV','WA')` so I don't have so many `state=`?

Also, does anyone have any sample queries for filter feature? The Filter feature is like when you do a search in a music website for songs based on genre or something. I apologize in advance for the confusing question, I can't find the right question to ask for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`IN()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php) :

```
WHERE state IN('CA','NV','WA'...)
```

Its not only doing the same effect, it's a lot more efficient then severals `OR`s , always try to avoid unnecessary `OR`'s .

As mentioned by @Kulvar , you can use `implode()` to make it work with PHP , something like:

```
'WHERE state IN(' . implode(',', $states) . ')'
```

Comment: implode() works great there :D `'WHERE state IN(' . implode(',', $states) . ')'`

Comment: So it won't work in PHP if I don't use implode()? What is $states, I don't have that variable :s

Comment: It's an easy way to compare array of values, you need to store all state options there, google php implode use. You can also specify manually all the options if you want. @jay